# I installed TeXStudio and MiKTeX in the wrong order. How can I do a clean install again?

Tags: installing, miktex, texstudio

So i am a noob at any kind of TeX. I quickly wanted to get up and running and downloaded `protex.exe`. I installed TeXStudio first, then MiKTeX, which is obviously wrong.

The problem is that when you uninstall TeXStudio and reinstall it, it still doesn't recognise MiKTeX.

I have tried to save a few pdf files with TeXStudio (just typing gibberish and saving it), but when I open them in adobe reader they are just corrupt. It does not give me an error however.

I have also opened some sample `.tex` files and tried to save them as `pdf`, to see if the program is working, and it also won't open the files in adobe reader.

How can I get TeXStudio to work, or am I missing something entirely?

(Windows 7 64 bit)

Comment: You don't get a pdf by *saving* something as pdf. You will have to compile the `tex` file.

Answer (score 9):

TeXstudio stores its settings in `texstudio.ini` which is located in `%APPDATA%\texstudio\`. If you delete the `.ini` while TeXstudio is closed, it will restart with default settings.

Answer (score 4):

It has an easy solution without reinstalling ***TeXstudio***

1. Close TeXStudio.
2. In Windows Explorer navigate to: `%APPDATA%\texstudio\\`
   (Alternatively you can navigate to `C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_ACCOUNT_NAME\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\\`).
3. Delete `texstudio.ini` file.
4. Restart TeXStudio.

It works for me :)

Comment: Should clarify: `AppData` is a hidden folder for most people, so they may not be able to see it without changing the system settings to show hidden folders.

Comment: Restart TeXStudio from "Program Files" or using a shortcut. Opening a .tex file doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The [`ProTeXt` install manual](http://www.math.uconn.edu/ITResources/LaTeXDownload/protext-install-en.pdf) says to uninstall, the re-install.

It worked for me.