# ERROR: beamer.cls not found

Tags: beamer, errors, packages, miktex

I installed MiKTex 2.9  and want to run a presentation, but always get the Error

"beamer.cls not found" as you can see in picture. The problem is that whenever I search beamer.cls in CTAN website I get nothing !! Where can I found this package ? And where should I send it?

Thanks for your kind helps[image]

following is the picture of all files I have in my MiKTex' file 
[image]

Comment: Please tell us more about how you installed MikTeX. Please also show us lines 1 and 2 of the tex file. (By the way, `beamer.cls` is not a "package" -- at least not in the LaTeX sense of the word. It's a so-called document class file.)

Comment: It was just few steps that I followed , nothing was odd! BTW I didn't install it in my program files ! does it make problem ?

Comment: afaik beamer should be part of any standard latex installation, thus I guess your editor doesn't recognize your local tex distribution. go to 'options > configure > commands'. Are all or most of the fields blank?

Comment: @Mico  I updated the picture.   

thymaro : No they have been filled out,  but  I installed Takmaker before MikTex ! Does is make problem ?

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71073/i-installed-texstudio-and-miktex-in-the-wrong-order-how-can-i-do-a-clean-instal) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202841/how-to-manually-configure-texstudio-for-windows-in-the-ctan-package-protext-3-1) might help you.

Comment: @thymaro  : Thank you. In addition to that if you look at second picture you see there is no file called "Maintenance"  !  Is that normal? I thought there is such file from there we can update packages ?

Comment: I don't have a miktex installation handy right now as I use that only at work (and it was installed for me, there). I really don't know what you mean by that and [miktex documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html) doesn't seem to know, either. When I want to do updates, I use `miktex update` and I install packages with `miktex package manager`. You might want to have a look at `miktex settings`, too. you can find those with your standard windows search. (I run them in admin mode, but I really don't remember, why)

Comment: Related: [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly) and somehow [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation)

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` in a beamer document. Also `\tiny` does not take arguments, so it should be `\tiny (cont.)`